# Extracting output before the softmax layer, then manually calculating softmax gives a different result

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, keras, entropy, softmax

I have a model trained to classify rgb values into 1000 categories.

```
#Model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,input_shape=(3,),activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1000,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1000,activation="softmax"))
```

I want to be able to extract the output before the softmax layer so I can conduct analyses on different samples of categories within the model. I want execute softmax for each sample, and conduct analyses using a function named getinfo().

1. Model
   Initially, I enter X_train data into model.predict, to get a vector of 1000 probabilities for each input. I execute getinfo() on this array to get the desired result.
2. Pop1
   I then use model.pop() to remove the softmax layer. I get new predictions for the popped model, and execute scipy.special.softmax. However, getinfo() produces an entirely different result on this array.
3. Pop2
   I write my own softmax function to validate the 2nd result, and I receive an almost identical answer to Pop1.
4. Pop3
   However, when I simply calculate getinfo() on the output of model.pop() with no softmax function, I get the same result as the initial Model.

```
data = np.loadtxt("allData.csv",delimiter=",")
model = load_model("model.h5")

def getinfo(data):
    objects = scipy.stats.entropy(np.mean(data, axis=0), base=2)
    print(('objects_mean',objects))
    colours_entropy = []
    for i in data:
        e = scipy.stats.entropy(i, base=2)
        colours_entropy.append(e)
    colours = np.mean(np.array(colours_entropy))
    print(('colours_mean',colours))
    info = objects - colours
    print(('objects-colours',info))
    return info

def softmax_max(data):
    # calculate softmax whilst subtracting the max values (axis=1)
    sm = []
    count = 0
    for row in data:
        max = np.argmax(row)
        e = np.exp(row-data[count,max])
        s = np.sum(e)
        sm.append(e/s)
    sm = np.asarray(sm)
    return sm

#model
preds = model.predict(X_train)
getinfo(preds)

#pop1
model.pop()
preds1 = model.predict(X_train)
sm1 = scipy.special.softmax(preds1,axis=1)
getinfo(sm1)

#pop2
sm2 = softmax_max(preds1)
getinfo(sm2)

#pop3
getinfo(preds1)
```

I expect to get the same output from Model, Pop1 and Pop2, but a different answer to Pop3, as I did not compute softmax here. I wonder if the issue is with computing softmax after model.predict? And whether I am getting the same result in Model and Pop3 because softmax is constraining the values between 0-1, so for the purpose of the getinfo() function, the result is mathematically equivalent?

If this is the case, then how do I execute softmax before model.predict?

I've gone around in circles with this, so any help or insight would be much appreciated. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.pop()` does not immediately have an effect. You need to run `model.compile()` again to recompile the new model that doesn't include the last layer.

Without the recompile, you're essentially running `model.predict()` twice in a row on the exact same model, which explains why Model and Pop3 give the same result. Pop1 and Pop2 give weird results because they are calculating the softmax of a softmax.

In addition, your model does not have the softmax as a separate layer, so `pop` takes off the entire last `Dense` layer. To fix this, add the softmax as a separate layer like so:

```
model.add(Dense(1000))           # softmax removed from this layer...
model.add(Activation('softmax')) # ...and added to its own layer
```

Comment: okay, so I add `model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimise="adam")` after `model.pop()`, however I still get a very different answer. Is there anything further I need to do to the model?

Comment: @Mubaraka Just realized that you're not using a separate activation layer. This means that `pop` takes off the last `Dense` layer, which you don't want. See my edit to this answer.

Comment: I see, so does that mean I need to adjust the model architecture and retrain the whole model?

Comment: @Mubaraka The softmax layer has no weights, so you should be able to the same weights you've been using. Alternately, you might be able to get away with simply setting `model.layers[-1].activation = None` and then recompiling.

Comment: Thank you so much, `model.layers[-1].activation` didn't seem to work, but loading the weights into a new model with an additional softmax layer worked perfectly.